# react-create-app how to import external jquery and bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I created a react app using react-create-app. Now I am not able to import external js and bootstrap files.

index.js

```
import './assets/css/style.css';
import './assets/css/bootstrap-social.css';
import './assets/css/bootstrap.css';
import './assets/css/responsive.css';
import './assets/css/theme-default.css';
import './assets/css/jquery-ui.css';
import './assets/css/main.css';
import './assets/css/font-awesome.css';
// const $ = require('./assets/js/jquery.min.js');
// global.jQuery = $
// const app = require('./assets/js/bootstrap.min.js');
```

I have purchased s theme. Not I want to install external jquery and bootstrap. Note: css import working fine.

Comment: maybe this could help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48069504/in-create-react-app-adding-bootstrap-4

Comment: here is my index.js code 

<pre>
import './assets/css/style.css';
import './assets/css/bootstrap-social.css';
import './assets/css/bootstrap.css';
import './assets/css/responsive.css';
import './assets/css/theme-default.css';
import './assets/css/jquery-ui.css';
import './assets/css/main.css';
import './assets/css/font-awesome.css';

const $ = require('jquery');
// global.jQuery = $
// const app = require('./assets/js/bootstrap.min.js');
</pre>

i have purchased theme. not want to install external jquery and bootstrap.  Note: css import working fine.

Comment: edit your question and add the above data into that

Comment: here is my index.js code

`import './assets/css/style.css'; 
import './assets/css/bootstrap-social.css'; 
import './assets/css/bootstrap.css'; 
import './assets/css/responsive.css'; 
import './assets/css/theme-default.css'; 
import './assets/css/jquery-ui.css'; 
import './assets/css/main.css'; 
import './assets/css/font-awesome.css'; 
//const $ = require('./assets/js/jquery.min.js'); 
// global.jQuery = $ 
// const app = require('./assets/js/bootstrap.min.js');`  

i have purchased theme. not want to install external jquery and bootstrap. Note: css import working fine.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I edited your question to incorporate the information you added in the comments (please check if I got everything right). You can do that by using the edit button below the question. Please also add the following information to your question: Where exactly are you stuck? Do you get an error message? If so, please add it to the question.

Comment: ok guys. i found the solution. I updated my package.json packages to its latest version and its working fine.